# VIM autocmd corrupts default register

Tags: vim, autocmd

I'm trying to update some text lines containing filenames in specific file in Vim. To do that I've added this in my .vimrc:

```
let logs_pat = "/ARCHIVE/logs/db_agent.log*"
au! BufEnter *_search.txt execute "/\\[DBA_LOGS\\]/,$d | $put = '[DBA_LOGS]' | $r!ls -t " . logs_pat . " | head "
```

It works fine except some artifacts. And **question** is about **how to eliminate those artifacts**.

Every time when I get into a buffer with file *_search.txt, 
**1)** the contents of the register "" is replaced by the text been added by autocmd to file *_search.txt **2)** a message appears on the vim status line: "10 more lines" or "search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP"

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/\\[DBA_LOGS\\]/,$d` command deletes the range of lines into the default register. To avoid that, append the *black hole register* (`_`). To suppress the message, prepend `:silent`.

```
au! BufEnter *_search.txt execute "silent /\\[DBA_LOGS\\]/,$delete _ | $put = '[DBA_LOGS]' | silent $r!ls -t " . logs_pat . " | head "
```

---

To maintain the original cursor position, you can wrap this with either:

```
:mark z
...
:normal! g`z
```

or

```
:let pos = getpos('.')
...
:call setpos('.', pos)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well. But I've noticed another bug: cursor changes its position to the last line of the file *_search.txt.